# Difference between Spline (spatial analyst) and Geostatistical Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, interpolation, geostatistical-analyst, spline

Why the interpolation result of Spline with Tension in the Spatial Analyst is different from the that in the Geostatistical Analyst (both in ArcGIS 10), including their minimum values, maximum values, and isopach?

Just as the maps below, with the same original date and corresponding parameter setting, fig. 1 is done by Spline with Tension in Spatial Analyst, fig. 2 is done by Spline in Geostatistical Analyst, and they are totally different.

What does the prediction map in Geostatistical Analyst exactly mean?

As we know, Spline is an exact interpolation method, but in Geostatistical Analyst, it seems not. Just as the yellow dots  in the fig. 2, the original value of them are all 0, but why they appear in different color bands in the prediction map, which means that their predicted value are different with their original value.

Why? I'm really confused about that.

Some further explanations:

- the yellow and red dots=0, and the values of the green dots are labeled in the figs, all of them are used to do the interpolation.
- Fig. 1 is understandable to me, which conforms with definition of Spline, and all the dots appear in the correct color areas that include their original data.
- I cann't understand fig. 2.

Why does the same interpolation method in different tools lead to very different results?

Forgive my poor English.

[image]

1. interpolation result of Spline with Tension in the Spatial Analyst

[image]

2. Prediction Map in the Geostatistical Analyst

Comment: Answer to this question is not very simple but I'll refer to read this link http://webapps.fundp.ac.be/geotp/SIG/interpolating.pdf I hope you find usefull

Comment: Which points are the data here? The labelled green ones, the red and yellow coloured ones? All of them (with yellow=zero, red=what)? Applying the same colour mapping to the two smoothings would help assess the difference also. The first one is stretched by that huge red blob of a peak at the top...

Comment: This is a very complex answer, hopefully it is on the board already if not maybe Bill will jump in, if not Ill try to get to it in the next day or two.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because to me the question is clear and specific: "why two different tools which (apparently) work under the same method lead to different outputs/results?". The OP has responded to comments accordingly; it is perhaps just a tough question, but not broad.

Comment: @AndreSilva It is too broad due to there being two questions.  If the question focused on just one then it'd possibly be OK

Comment: @Midavalo, two questions probably answerable with one answer, because they are closely related (if not the same). It is only too broad when 2 questions or more would demand completely different answers. In this case, it is clear there is one main question, and the second one could be considered another way to ask the first question but using a different wording (in my opinion).

Comment: I'll vote to re-open when either the asker, or someone helping them, edits the question to be a single question as per the [Tour].  Two questions probably answerable with one answer should probably end up being one clear Q&A with a duplicate Q.  The tougher the question the clearer it needs to be to attract potential answerers.

Answer (score -1):

You can find Comparing interpolation methods in below link.
[link]http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/comparing-interpolation-methods.html
I hope this figure and below description can be helpfully
[Comparing figure for IDW, Kriging and Spline]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZmhi.jpg)
IDW and Spline are two deterministic methods that create surfaces
from samples based on the extent of similarity or degree of smoothing.
However, while a spline surface passes exactly through each
sample point, an IDW will pass through none of the points. Kriging is
a geostatistical method that uses a powerful statistical technique for
predicting values derived from the measure of relationship in samples
and employs sophisticated weighted average techniques.

Comment: Thank you. But what I want to know is that the same interpolation method performs quite different in different analyst tools. Your link doesn't say something about that.

Comment: Did you see my link in comment also?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I used the same interpolation method (in different tools), but got different results.

Comment: I see, I'll say in my opinion they aren't same, they have many differences, it back to parameter and algorithm run behind each tools.